# Rails option_for_select related – is there a way to remember value if present and include blank if value is blank?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, select

This is what I am using right now. Is there a way to dry this up a bit?? Repetitive code, not to mention the functionality I need is straight forward and simple: show value if value is present and show blank if value is not present. Can I just throw in an if or unless statement at the end which will show value if present (and remove an entire block of code)??

```
<div class="field">
  <% if @user.nation.present? %><br/>
    <%= f.label :nation %><br />
    <%= f.select :nation, options_for_select(%w[
      Canada
      England
      Caribbean
    ], @user.nation) %><br/>
  <% else %><br/>
    <%= f.label :nation %><br />
    <%= f.select :nation, options_for_select(%w[
    Canada
    England
    Caribbean
    ]), { :include_blank => 'Where Do You Live?' } %><br/>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Given your question (Where do you live) I assume you don't want a blank value so you can just use a prompt:

```
<%= f.select :nation, options_for_select(%w[
      Canada
      England
      Caribbean
    ], @user.nation), prompt: 'Where Do You Live' %>
```

If not then you should be able to use the ternary operator to do the if inline rather than having a large chunk of code repeated.

```
<%= f.select :nation, options_for_select(%w[
    Canada
    England
    Caribbean
    ]), { :include_blank => (@user.nation.present? ? false : 'Where Do You Live?' ) } %>
```